# Will Go make a copy of my struct if I return by value, instead of a pointer?

Tags: go, memory-management, return, heap-memory, rvo

Take this example:

```
type Foo struct {
    num int
}

// func NewFoo() *Foo { // returning a pointer
//     return &Foo{33}
// }

func NewFoo() Foo { // NOT returning a pointer
    return Foo{33}
}

func main() {
    fff := NewFoo()
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", fff.num)
}
```

If `NewFoo` returns a pointer, I understand the object is kept in the heap, and `fff` receives the pointer to the very same heap-allocated object.

Now, with the second implementation of `NewFoo`, which won't return a pointer, will Go return a **copy** of the stack-allocated struct, or is there something like [C++'s RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) taking place?

Comment: This is unspecified and may vary from compiler to compiler. Note that your assumptions about being heap-/stack-allocated are unfounded too. Not to speak of inlining calls to NewFoo.

Comment: @Volker So Go may deliberately alloc a struct in the heap?

Comment: In general, the semantics will be equivalent of copying the struct, but whether or not copying really takes place depends on the implementation. If the function is inlined, there would be no need for copying.

Comment: Yes it can decide. It uses escape analysis https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it by following these steps:

1. Write your program in a file say `main.go` like this: https://play.golang.org/p/iwxai0EHa40
2. Execute the command `go build -gcflags=-m main.go`
3. See the output to really know if it is being copied/inlined. In my case the output I get is:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:13:6: can inline NewFoo
./main.go:17:6: can inline main
./main.go:18:15: inlining call to NewFoo
./main.go:19:12: inlining call to fmt.Printf
./main.go:19:24: fff.num escapes to heap
./main.go:19:12: io.Writer(os.Stdout) escapes to heap
./main.go:19:12: main []interface {} literal does not escape
<autogenerated>:1: os.(*File).close .this does not escape
```

This procedure you can follow in any Go program to check if there is any unnecessary heap allocation occurring in your program which you can avoid.

[Here is a short article](https://tennexas.com/how-to-check-improve-performance-in-go/) which goes through various ways you can make your program more efficient.

Comment: I guess in that sense that example is not going to be that good. Would Golang inline code from a library using such a copy? How does it decide to inline or not? What if we start a go routine? I think there are many parameters that can make it really difficult to give a straight answer on that question.